# how did they get this domain for this trig function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Solve the ODE and give the largest interval I over which the general solution is defined.

$\cos x \frac{dy}{dx} + (\sin x)y=1$

I got the solution $y=sinx+c \cdot cosx$ but how did they get the interval of solution to be $(\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$?

Comment: Think about how you got your solution. If you had to divide by something which is zero at $\pm\frac\pi2$, then the solution probably won't be defined there.

Comment: @Jason actually that's something I don't understand well. So if an intermediate result is undefined, then that propagates to the solution and makes it undefined there too?

Comment: You can also look at it this way: $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}y+1$. See where the derivative is defined.